# How can I inhibit typeahead programmatically?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have an input field with typeahead.js enabled on it. However, there are times when I need the user to type text in the field without it triggering further suggestions. The use case is that I have previously selected an item suggested via typeahead, and then I want to rename it without losing the reference I acquired earlier.

I would like to be able to tell the typeahead instance not to trigger suggestion and later enable them again, possibly in a way not so radical as by destroying and recreating the typeahead. I am guessing that I could capture a `typeahead:active` event and somehow tell it not to proceed further, but stopping event propagation does't seem to do it for me.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please share your current attempts.

Comment: Well the only thing I really tried was to call `$([name="inputname"]).typeahead('destroy')` to disable typeahead, and then enable it by re-creating it `$([name="inputname"]).typeahead(options, [*datasets])`, but that affects the DOM quite dramatically (causing some CSS and jQuery selectors not to work anymore) and just doesn't seem the right way.

Comment: What I'm doing right now is to prevent the dropdown menu from showing by capuring the event where it opens, using `$([name="inputname"]).on('typeahead:open',function(){ $(this).typeahead('close') })`. Needless to say this is less than optimal, as it doesn't prevent the Ajax requests etc. from firing.